# How to find index of last element in list matching predicate?

Tags: f#

I would like to get the last index of an element in a list matching a predicate. I know I can use the following code for an array, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this for a list (without converting to an array and using the below function):

```
let tryFindLastIndex f (arr: 'a []) =
    let rec loop n (arr: 'a []) =
        match n with
        | -1 -> None
        | n ->
            if f arr.[n] then Some n
            else loop (n-1) arr
    loop (arr.Length - 1) arr
```

Comment: The code would be very similar - but with pattern matching on the list, rather than indexing into it. Have you tried anything along those lines? What problems are you running into?

Comment: (Sorry, I didn't realize that you were iterating through the array _backwards_. That makes it more interesting!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` in F# is a linked list you can't easily iterate in last->first direction. Because of that you have to iterate from the beginning and keep the track of both current index and index of last element that matches the predicate.

You still use local recursive function to do that.

```
let tryFindLastIndex f source =
    let rec loop index lastFoundIndex source =
        let newIndex = index+1
        match source with
        | [] -> lastFoundIndex
        | head :: tail ->
            if f head then loop newIndex (Some index) tail
            else loop newIndex lastFoundIndex tail
    loop 0 None source
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd approach this task with idiomatic use of library functions and combinators:

```
let tryFindLastIndex f ls =
    match ls |> (List.rev >> List.tryFindIndex f) with
    | None -> None
    | Some n -> Some (ls.Length - n - 1)
```

**EDIT**: for those who are over concerned with performance, the same can be achieved by single list traverse with the same clarity of intent still using library functions and combinators:

```
let tryFindLastIndex f ls =
    match (ls |> List.fold (fun (i,r) l -> if f l then (i+1,i::r) else (i+1,r)) (0,[]) |> snd) with
    | [] -> None
    | x -> Some (x.Head)
```

Comment: It requires at least 2 full passes over the collection (for `List.rev` and `ls.length`) + in the worst case when no elements match the condition a third one (`List.tryFindIndex`).

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I do not see any indication that question has performance concerns, so why bother? If performance is a concern, a different, but still idiomatic approach may be applied - see the edited answer.